# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая:
«На основании статьи 153 Гражданского кодекса Республики Беларусь и руководствуясь статьей 6 Гражданского процессуального кодекса Республики Беларусь(,) прошу…»

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может, в деловых бумагах так и принято, не знаю, но с точки зрения нормативной грамматики здесь ошибка. Второстепенные члены "На основании..." и "руководствуясь..." не очень однородны. Я бы союз "и" убрала, а запятую поставила, выделив деепричастный оборот.

*«На основании статьи 153 Гражданского кодекса Республики Беларусь, руководствуясь статьей 6 Гражданского процессуального кодекса Республики Беларусь, прошу…»*